# Backup software that can split files to 3 separate disks

Tags: windows, backup, drive

I have 3To of storage on a RAID5 configuration, and I want to setup a regular backup of these 3To of data on external disks that I would bring to a separate physical location (my office). I have 3 external drives of 1To each. I could of course use Windows (the server holding the NAS is running a regular windows 10 copy) to create a software RAID 0 with the 3 disks, but in case one of them fails I'd lost all the data.
I wonder if there is a backup software that is able to automatically split the files to backup in 3 sections of approx the same size and write each section on a different external drive?

Comment: Why not just purchase a hard drive large enough for the backup? You can purchase a 10TB external hard drive for less than $200.00 USD.

Comment: that would be an option, but I already have 3 internal drives + their external housing I don't use, and even a spare one (internal) in case one dies. Someone suggested me to use the disk manager's new spanned volume, but for what I read this is not fault tolerant.

Comment: I see down votes on the topic. If this is a bad idea to do a backup this way please explain me why, I'm open :-)

Comment: After you do your research to select a backup system that can output multiple part archives to different media, how is the implementation going for you? And did you evaluate larger single media, note that there are tape, spindle, and SSDs  in sizes larger than 4 TB.  Its not that you have a bad idea, rather you haven't shown your work.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't get it. English is not my native language, and I'm not sure to understand what you mean. To give more context: I'm an individual, and I wish to have a proper backup of my data (incl. in case of robbery or house fire), but my data is not as critical as a large industry's. I'm not sure it is worth buying a tape or spindle recorder and medias. I wish to use 3 1TB drives because I already have them, actually.

Comment: The goal for me is to do 1 incremental or full backup per month, and then store the drives at my office between 2 backups. The restore can be done by just copying the files. As I have separate drives, I could use this to split my files in 3, so if I'm really unlucky and 1 drive fails, I still can recover 2/3rd of the backed up data.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to backup 3TB of data, then the most realiable, easy and probably cheapest solution would be to purchase a new 4TB disk. They cost 50-100 USD nowadays. It is not a huge investment to protect personal files you value.

Approaching this from software perspective, like using some sofisticated software to split files, will highly likely do more harm than good.

And if you want to protect the backup itself, just buy two of these. You can also move one of them offsite occasionally, to cover robbery scenario